# Word wrap/break and keep upper's line indent

Tags: css

I have problems with wrong word-breaking/word-wrapping (what's the difference? synonyms?). I want something like I've marked it in the screenshot. In case there is a line break due to a small window/screen the word should be breaked to the next line but keep upper's line indent. Any ideas?

[image]

My HTML-structure is the following:

```css
//Sorry, I thought my CSS is not necessary because it's a general //problem with an easy solution.

nav ul, nav li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: block;
  /*height:46px;*/
  line-height: 46px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav li .router-link-active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
nav ul i.material-icons {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

nav {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul lass="nav-links">
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neuen Nutzer anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neuen Verkauf anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neues Objekt anlegen</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: please add css of this..

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:absolute` to your `i` tag and give `position:relative` to a tag and set `i` tag top and left position.

```
<ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <span>Neuen Nutzer anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <span>Neuen Verkauf anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <span>Neues Objekt anlegen</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-links{
  list-style:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:150px;
}
.nav-links li {
    display: block;
    /*height:46px;*/
    line-height: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.nav-links li:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.nav-links li .router-link-active {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-left: 15px;
     position:relative;
     padding-left:30px;
}
.nav-links li i {
    color: #666;
    font-size: 19px;   
    padding-right: 17px;
    position:absolute;
    left:5px;
    top:5px
}
```

Here is jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/x82dxx1L/1/

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
    span{
       word-break:normal;
   }
   li>a>i{
     float: left;
   }
```

HTML:

```
   <ul lass="nav-links">
        <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
                <span>Neuen Nutzer <br> anlegen</span></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
                <span>Neuen Verkauf anlegen</span></a></li>
        <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
                <span>Neues Objekt anlegen</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yz4c36wc/1/

Answer (score 0):

Position your `<a>` items as `relative`, then set the `<span>`s' `position`s to `absolute`, and set the `left` value of the `span`s to the width of the pencil image

```css
nav ul, nav li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
nav li {
  display: block;
  /*height:46px;*/
  line-height: 46px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
nav li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav li .router-link-active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
nav a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  font-size: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
nav ul i.material-icons {
  color: #666;
  font-size: 19px;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  padding-right: 17px;
}

nav {
  width: 200px;
}

nav li span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul lass="nav-links">
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neuen Nutzer anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neuen Verkauf anlegen</span></a></li>
    <li><a><i class="material-icons">create</i>
      <span>Neues Objekt anlegen</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. U can pic to marker for li

   li {
     list-style-image: url(images/pic.png);
   }
2. U can give to span display:block; and play with word wrap:

   i,
   span {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   a {
     white-space: nowrap;
   }
   span {
     white-space: normal;
   }